# How to do spacing to print like a table?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-tablayout

I am trying to print data in a table format where the columns name and position are fixed and it is defined in xml file.

```
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="sid"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                    android:id="@+id/textView16" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="  firstName"
                    android:id="@+id/textView16" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="  lastName"
                    android:id="@+id/textView16" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="  address"
                    android:id="@+id/textView16" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="  phone"
                    android:id="@+id/textView16" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

and the java code for print data is:

```
    String sql=editQueryDB2.getText().toString();
                cursor = dbHelper.rawsqlquery(sql);

                if(cursor!=null) {
                    names = cursor.getColumnNames();
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        for (String name : names) {
                            finalData.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(name)));
                            finalData.append(" - ");
                        }
                        finalData.append("\n");
                    }
                    submittedQueryDB2.setText(finalData);
                }
```

Output:
[image]

The printing of data is not proper as it will vary according to data present in table.So is there any way to print systematically in table format.

Comment: Is there any function like in C language %6d for spacing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\t`, tab space between the entries.

Comment: 1        vishal           gupta         sanatacruz          111112 .                             2        suryakumar gupta         sanatacruz          11452                                    can i allocate some space to attributes they will expand only if they need more space .Hence it will print table like structure. Reply

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use multiple \t to adjust your tablelike textview. I guess you just used one \t between each column which might not be adequate, you should search for the optimum tab number for your data.

However, you can also use Table instead of TextView:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tv);

TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("1");
tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

tr.addView(tv1);

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
tv2.setText("vishal");
tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

tr.addView(tv2);

...

tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```